# Problemas al querer instalar la extension HGFLOW en el controlador de versiones Mercurial

Tags: windows, cmd, mercurial

Hy tendría que tener el primer trabajo como freelancer y mi empresa trabaja con Mercurial entonces tuve que instalarlo y lo pude hacer correctamente, pero al intentar instalar la extensión HGFLOW es donde está mi problema, para poder agregar la extensión debo agregar en el archivo Mercurial.ini la ruta en donde se encuentra la extensión descargada, pero al hacerlo e intentar utilizar los comandos que me brinda la extensión no funciona. Les adjunto imágenes:

Acá está descargada la extensión:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá están las configuraciones de Mercurial.ini:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y acá está las instrucciones de lo que debo hacer:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando ejecuto el comando hg flow help en el cmd me aparece como si no existiera el comando, pero al ejecutar ese comando en la carpeta donde tengo señalizada en el archivo Mercurial.ini se me crea otro archivo con la extensión .pyo

Les adjunto el cmd:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]